# Swagger2 in Spring Boot app doesn't pick up @ApiResponses with custom Docket

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a controller handler method:

```
@ApiResponses({
    @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "aaa", response = Response.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "bbb")
})
@PostMapping("api/aa")
public Response save() {
    ...
}
...
```

Whenever I add a custom Docket configuration as below. `@ApiResponse` defined in `@ApiResponses` don't seem to work anymore. As I no longer see them showing up on the UI or under `v2/api-docs`'s json. Any ideas what I am missing?

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SPRING_WEB)
        .host(kongHost)
        .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.mypackage.controller"))
        .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/*"))
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I would need to specify the `DocumentationType` to be `SWAGGER_2`